# How to check if the machine/system is touch enabled or not in a JavaFx application?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

We have a JavaFx app and in certain situations we need to know if the Windows machine on which app is running is touch enabled or not. Still not able to figure out any decent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but according to the documentation:

```
Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.INPUT_TOUCH)
```

and

```
Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.INPUT_MULTITOUCH)
```

From the JavaDoc:

> On embedded platforms JavaFX makes an attempt to initialize this
>   ConditionalFeature based on what input peripherals are attached. On
>   desktop platforms this ConditionalFeature will typically default to
>   false.

Comment: On desktop platforms both ConditionalFeature above will typically default to ***false***.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Still need to test this though.

Comment: @Leet-Falcon Yes, of course, that's why I posted it. Copy & paste error. Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It works at least on Linux Mint (returns `true` on Asus with touchscreen and `false` on PC).

Answer (score 0):

[ConditionalFeature](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html) Defines a set of conditional (optional) features.
An application that wants to know whether a particular feature is available may query this using: [`Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/application/Platform.html#isSupported-javafx.application.ConditionalFeature-)

For touch features the following are available:
[ConditionalFeature.INPUT_TOUCH](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#INPUT_TOUCH)
[ConditionalFeature.INPUT_MULTITOUCH](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#INPUT_MULTITOUCH)

Since:
JavaFX 8.0

Comment: I have tried this but this is returning "false" in a Windows 10 based tablet.

Comment: Maybe setting -Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true & -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true will help

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the "ConditionalFeature" method indeed doesn't work on "non embedded" systems like a Surface Pro for example (probably counts for other touch enabled notebooks too).
However in that case you can use the `setOnTouchPressed((TouchEvent))` method to detect at least when a touch is applied. That works reliably and distinguishes from touchpad or mouse.
Haven't found a solution to detect directly at startup either unfortunately.